# Netbeans: debugging Java Servlet on Tomcat opens two debug consoles?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have been developing a Java Servlet app over several years. I have recently started to have slight problems debugging the app with Netbeans. When I click "Debug Project" under the Debug-menu in Netbeans 11.1, the following happens:

1. Tomcat is started and the app is deployed.
2. A debugger console is opened that says "User program running".
3. The app is recompiled.
4. There seems to be an attempt to somehow redeploy/debug(?) the app again: a second debugger console is opened but this one says "Connection refused".

Historically only steps 1-2 have occurred. I have no idea why recently also steps 3-4 have started to occur. E.g. the only changes I have done to the project pom-file is that some dependencies have been updated to a newer version. The only other major changes have been that the underlying Java SDK is now for version 12 and Netbeans has been updated from 8.2 to 11.1.

The end result is sort of half-ok: I am able to debug (set breakpoints, view variables etc.) the app. But one annoyance is that hot redeploying does not seem to work anymore. Previously changing and saving a Java code file caused that one file to be recompiled and the updated app to be redeployed automatically. This does not happen anymore if I modify and save Java code; I have to compile and redeploy manually. And of course also the fact that the whole project is recompiled at the beginning of each debug session slows things down. I assume these problems must be related to how the extra steps 3-4 have started to occur, but have no idea what could trigger those.

I wonder if anyone has any ideas what might cause this?